# ruby rails binding.pry how to step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

What are the terminal commands to step over a line of code while using ruby rails 'binding.pry'? In addition do you know the command to step into, step out of, and continue?

Here is an example:

```
def add_nums
    x = 5 + 5
    binding.pry
    x += 5
    x += 7
    return x
end
```

I'd like to know how to step through this method and in my terminal to see what the value of 'x' is until it is returned. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to type `help` at a prompt to see available commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Inelegant Solution**

Since you have access to the scope of `x`, manually enter each line (or anything you want) and see how it impacts your variable.

**More Elegant Solution**

Check out either [PryDebugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger) (MRI 1.9.2+) or [Pry ByeBug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) (MRI 2+) which give you controls to manually step through code. If you choose ByeBug the brief syntax example is:

```
def some_method
  puts 'Hello World' # Run 'step' in the console to move here
end

binding.pry
some_method          # Execution will stop here.
puts 'Goodbye World' # Run 'next' in the console to move here.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

`next` executes that line of code and proceeds to the next line. `step` steps into a function. `quit` lets the program continue running.